# WPF ListView Pagination using MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, pagination

A few days ago, I was looking for simple pagination example and I decided to write my own version. It is one of my first apps using MVVM Pattern, so I am not sure I did right. I would appreciate if you could tell if I did something wrong, or used bad programming practises or whatever.

[GitHub](http://github.com/Dessembrae/MVVM-ListView-Pagination)

**`MainWindow`:**

```xml
<Window x:Class="MVVMListViewPagination.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:MVVMListViewPagination.Views"
    Title="MVVM - ListView Pagination" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="45" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ViewList.View}" Margin="5">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Id" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Surname}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <userControls:PaginationElements Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" />

</Grid>
```

**User Control with buttons for pagination:**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMListViewPagination.Views.PaginationElements"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button Content="First" Command="{Binding FirstCommand}"/>
    <Button Content="Previous" Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}"/>
    <TextBlock Width="auto" Text="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="of"/>
    <TextBlock Width="auto" Text="{Binding TotalPage}"/>
    <Button Content="Next" Command="{Binding NextCommand}"/>
    <Button Content="Last" Command="{Binding LastCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**`ViewModel`:**

```cs
namespace MVVMListViewPagination.ViewModels
{
    class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        #region Commands
        public ICommand PreviousCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand NextCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand FirstCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand LastCommand { get; private set; }
        #endregion

        #region Fields And Properties
        int itemPerPage = 15;
        int itemcount;
        private int _currentPageIndex;
        public int CurrentPageIndex
        {
            get { return _currentPageIndex; }
            set { _currentPageIndex = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPage"); }
        }
        public int CurrentPage
        {
            get { return _currentPageIndex + 1; }
        }

        private int _totalPage;
        public int TotalPage
        {
            get { return _totalPage; }
            set { _totalPage = value; OnPropertyChanged("TotalPage"); }
        }

        public CollectionViewSource ViewList { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Person> peopleList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        #endregion

        #region Pagination Methods
        public void ShowNextPage()
        {
            CurrentPageIndex++;
            ViewList.View.Refresh();
        }

        public void ShowPreviousPage()
        {
            CurrentPageIndex--;
            ViewList.View.Refresh();
        }

        public void ShowFirstPage()
        {
            CurrentPageIndex = 0;
            ViewList.View.Refresh();
        }

        public void ShowLastPage()
        {
            CurrentPageIndex = TotalPage - 1;
            ViewList.View.Refresh();
        }

        void view_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = ((Person)e.Item).Id - 1;
            if (index >= itemPerPage * CurrentPageIndex && index < itemPerPage * (CurrentPageIndex + 1))
            {
                e.Accepted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
        }

        private void CalculateTotalPages()
        {
            TotalPage = (itemcount / itemPerPage);
            if (itemcount % itemPerPage != 0)
            {
                TotalPage += 1;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            populateList();

            ViewList = new CollectionViewSource();
            ViewList.Source = peopleList;
            ViewList.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(view_Filter);

            CurrentPageIndex = 0;
            itemcount = peopleList.Count;
            CalculateTotalPages();

            NextCommand = new NextPageCommand(this);
            PreviousCommand = new PreviousPageCommand(this);
            FirstCommand = new FirstPageCommand(this);
            LastCommand = new LastPageCommand(this);
        }

        private void populateList()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                peopleList.Add(new Person(i, "Jack", "Black"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**One of the `Command` classes:**

```cs
namespace MVVMListViewPagination.Commands
{
    class FirstPageCommand : ICommand
    {
        private MainViewModel viewModel;

        public FirstPageCommand(MainViewModel viewModel)
        {
            this.viewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (viewModel.CurrentPageIndex == 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            viewModel.ShowFirstPage();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not a professional programmer, so all my knowledge comes from tutorials. I was trying to mantain a MVVM Pattern and I would like to know if I succeeded, as well as any constructive criticism about my skills as a programmer overall.

Answer (score 3):

**First**

> as well as any constructive criticism about my skills as a programmer
>   overall

We don't criticise skills. We only review code.

**Good**

- Sometimes using braces `{}` for `if..else` statement
- Naming of methods, parameter and fields based on naming convention

**Bad**

- Sometimes using no braces `{}` for `if..else` statement
- Inconsistent naming of variables ( somtimes with underscore , sometimes without )
- Using no [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) where `private` would be better for readability and consistence
- Some namings should be changed

Why is using `{}` braces, also for a single line of an `..if..else` statement, important ? See [Apple Bug](http://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2014/03/apples-gotofail-ssl-security-bug-was-easily-preventable/)

**Refactoring**

- **FirstPageCommand**

  We should use `braces` for the `if..else` statement in the
  `CanExecute()` method.

  ```
  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
      if (viewModel.CurrentPageIndex == 0)
      {
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```

  but we can do this better, as we don't need this `if..else` statement
  at all, at least as long there isn't passed / used / needed the
  `parameter`

  ```
  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
      return viewModel.CurrentPageIndex != 0
  }
  ```
- **MainViewModel**

  > ```
  > int itemPerPage = 15;
  > int itemcount;
  > ```

  should be

  ```
   private int itemPerPage = 15;
   private int itemcount;
  ```

  > ```
  > public int CurrentPageIndex
  > {
  >     get { return _currentPageIndex; }
  >     set { _currentPageIndex = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPage"); }
  > }
  > ```

  This will confuse **Mr.Maintainer** as this is not as readable as it
  could. So let us change it in the way that each get a separate line and also the setter should be private.

  ```
  public int CurrentPageIndex
  {
      get { return _currentPageIndex; }
      private set 
      { 
          _currentPageIndex = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPage"); 
      }
  }
  ```

  Another naming issue

  > ```
  > private int _totalPage;
  > public int TotalPage
  > {
  >     get { return _totalPage; }
  >     set { _totalPage = value; OnPropertyChanged("TotalPage"); }
  > }
  > ```

  Here we should use the plural form for the backing field and the
  property

  ```
  private int _totalPages;
  public int TotalPages
  {
      get { return _totalPages; }
      set 
      { 
        _totalPages = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("TotalPages"); 
      }
  }
  ```

  but wait.. does the setter need to be public ? Not really so let us
  instead use a `private set`

  ```
  public int TotalPages
  {
      get { return _totalPages; }
      private set 
      { 
        _totalPages = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("TotalPages"); 
      }
  }
  ```

  > ```
  > private void CalculateTotalPages()
  > {
  >     TotalPage = (itemcount / itemPerPage);
  >     if (itemcount % itemPerPage != 0)
  >     {
  >         TotalPage += 1;
  >     }
  > }
  > ```

  Let us see what this code is doing.  First is it assigning the value
  of `(itemcount / itemPerPage)` to the former `TotalPage` property.
  Then it is checking if the modulo is !=0 and if this is true it is
  adding 1. The adding 1 will involve the setter and the getter of the
  property. So the `OnPropertyChanged` event will fire twice.

  So let us refactor the method

  ```
  private void CalculateTotalPages()
  {
      if (itemcount % itemPerPage == 0)
      {
          TotalPages = (itemcount / itemPerPage);
      }
      else
      {
          TotalPages = (itemcount / itemPerPage) + 1;
      }
  }
  ```

  > ```
  > public ObservableCollection<Person> peopleList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
  > ```

  What about the scope of `peopleList` ? Does it need to be public ?
  Let us change the scope of `peopleList` to private and add a public
  `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` property

  ```
  private ObservableCollection<Person> peopleList = new ObservableCollection<Person>(); 
  public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person> PeopleList 
  { 
      get { return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person>(peopleList); } 
  }
  ```

Comment: "Using no access modifier (which defaults to internal) where private would be better" That's not true, default access for members is `private` (it's `internal` only for top-level types).

Comment: Thanks for review. I didn't know about the  rule about braces. I fixed my code on GitHub, don't know if I should do it in here as well? And you didn't say anything about MVVM pattern, did I used it right? And about naming convention - I only use underscore to private properties, should I use it also with regular private fields?

Comment: @Dess: The thing about braces is absolutely **not** a rule. It can be dangerous if someone used to python tries to add something at the same indentation level to put it within the conditional (which will not work). I generally avoid unneeded braces, but it can be a safety measure. As for underscore prefixes, they are also completely arbitrary. Your IDE is almost certainly smart enough to color `private`s differently from `public`s. If it helps you though, use it. 'Always use braces' is probably agreed upon by 70% of people, while underscores are more like 40%.

Comment: Another optimization: check if the the value actually changed before rising property changed in property setters.